# Help identifying component

Tags: wire

Sorry if this is not a question in the classical sense of stack exchange.

What is the cap that locks the wires called in the attached picture? I've not been able to identifying them with a fair bit of googling. Posting here as last resort.

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: looks a bit like one segment of a chocolate block.

Comment: Looks like audiophile "special" zero-ohm silver-plated multi-strand pointless cable to me so I bet those plastic things are going to be expensive in order to ensure the audio distortion remains below 1 part per billion.

Comment: Screw terminals on stranded cables without ferrules, what a travesty.

Comment: @Andyaka No way, this is generic chinese PVC speaker cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a single screw terminal block

[image]

http://www.radioparts.com.au/product/43322001/tbl2001-each-single-screw-terminal-block-32amp-450v-max#.Vk2jd3bhD0M

Also:

http://wholesaler.alibaba.com/product-detail/Australian-35A-6MM2-Single-Screw-terminal_952568246.html?spm=a2700.7724857.29.156.HeJqgZ

Comment: Isn't clamping several cables under one screw considered bad practice? (Maybe that should be an own question?)

Comment: It's often done in light fittings, and other domestic electric circuits, good practice or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In that picture, the terminals are being used to connect mains to a parallel circuit of light bulbs.